# .htaccess wild card redirect myweb.com/maindir/subdir/abcd.php to abcd.php?param=123

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am new to .htaccess
I am using apache rewrite to give access to virtual directories

**following code works**

```html
RewriteRule ^maindir/subdir/prog1.php?$   prog1.php?schoolid=12 [L] 
RewriteRule ^maindir/subdir/prog2.php?$   prog2.php?schoolid=12 [L] 
RewriteRule ^maindir/subdir/prog3.php?$   prog3.php?schoolid=12 [L] 
RewriteRule ^maindir/subdir/prog4.php?$   prog4.php?schoolid=12 [L] 
RewriteRule ^maindir/subdir/prog5.php?$   prog5.php?schoolid=12 [L] 
RewriteRule ^maindir/subdir/prog6.php?$   prog6.php?schoolid=12 [L]
```

but,
Instead of writing htacess code for each program prog1.php, prog2.php etc
can i use wild card...

Need your help

so that

****https://abcd.com/maindir/subdir/anyprogram.com**
will be actually executes
**https://abcd.com/anyprogram.com****

I tried (so as to use wild card in htaccess)

```html
RewriteRule ^maindir/subdir/(.*)$ 1?schoolid=12 [R,L] 
RewriteRule ^maindir/subdir/? https://abcd.com/?schoolid=12 [L,NE,R=301]
RewriteRule ^maindir/subdir/?$ $1?schoolid=12 [L,NE,R=301]
```

**but failed**

Comment: Try `RewriteRule ^maindir/subdir/prog([0-9]+)\.php$ prog$1.php?schoolid=12 [L] `

Comment: thanks "prog([0-9]+)" can be anything I had specified prog1, prog2 etc so that I can explain my requirement Actual requirement can be RewriteRule ^maindir/subdir/admin1.php?$   admin1.php?schoolid=12 [L] 
RewriteRule ^maindir/subdir/login.php?$   login.php?schoolid=12 [L] 
RewriteRule ^maindir/subdir/divisionadd.php?$   divisionadd.php?schoolid=12 [L]  ..In this can what change is required

Comment: I tried RewriteRule ^maindir/subdir/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)\.php$  $1.php?schoolid=12 [L] ........... works !! Thanks a tons for in time help